# Login session id's with hash

Tags: security, session, cookies, authentication, digital-signature

I have read that the usual way of handling login sessions is by storing a long random string server-side and setting a cookie with this string as its value.

What are the reasons why one shouldn't try to eliminate the load on the server by using a different method. The method I'm most concerned about is storing a cookie containing info about the logged in user (and session, etc...), and ensure the authenticity of the cookie by signing it instead of persisting cookie-specific data server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done properly, this can be just as secure as the random cookie solution.  It can be a bit harder to get right though.  (Remember, you can't store secret values in the cookie.)

However, done properly, it may not reduce load on the server either.  While you no longer need to look up (some of) the session information, you do need to perform cryptographic operations on every request to validate the cookie.  (This can be very CPU expensive.)

When I built a solution similar to this several years ago for a system that didn't support sessions, the cookies consisted of both the data (which was encrypted with AES128) and a Message Authentication Code (HMAC_SHA256). Only after it underwent significant security review were we comfortable deploying it.

Answer (score 2):

Any data used only by the server is a lot more secure then reading usernames and passwords form cookies, the less overall data you make the server handle is probably better untill you need security.

Typicaly you should only need a token cookie to link to a session ID so you can stay logged in without storing a password.

Comment: Thank you, I was actually thinking about doing something similar but I have no experience so I thought I must be thinking "gibberish".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're tracking a user by associating them with their session ID after login:

If you store all state on the client side in a signed cookie (even if it is just their login ID, for instance), you risk users acting as other users if your signing key(s) are ever compromised.  You can mitigate that to some extent by using a separate signing key per user, but now you need to use a cookie to track which signing key a user is using.  You could also try using a temporal scheme for signing keys (e.g. rotate them every 5 minutes), but now you're placing signing load on your server to re-generate cookie signatures every 5 minutes for all sessions.

It's far less computationally intense, and probably practically more secure, to store a computationally difficult hash value as the session identifier in the cookie, and associate that hash value with the user ID on the server side - you only have to generate the hash once, then look it up (which is easy) each time a web request comes in.